# Python Encapsulation in deep

Tags: python, oop, encapsulation

```
class Computer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__maxprice = 900
        self.minvalue = 200
   

c = Computer()
#print(c.__maxprice) # this will throw an exception
c.__maxprice = 1000 # hear am assigning the new value to my mangled variable
print(c.__maxprice) # this will return the value 1000
```

As per the encapsulation __maxprice should not be accessible outside but in the above example i am able to update the value and access it.

Comment: You're not accessing the same private attribute when you use `__maxprice` outside the class. There's no mangling outside the class.

Comment: Define a method that prints `self.__maxprice` and it will print `200`.

Comment: but what is happening when i update the value of mangling variable? can you explain more on it please.

Answer (score 0):

Within a class definition, attributes beginning with two underscores are mangled to `_classname__attribute`. So when you write `self.__maxprice` inside the class, it's treated as `self._Computer__maxprice`.

This mangling doesn't happen outside the class definition. So when you write

```
c.__maxprice = 1000
```

it creates a new attribute named `__maxprice`. This is unrelated to the attribute `_Computer__maxprice` that's assigned in the `__init__()` method.